# При переходе по ссылке на страницу записи не отображаются стандартные стили wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

я делаю тему для Wordpress и встала задача использования встроенного в Wordpress редактора и вывода записей кастомного типа "blog".

Все работает, но при переходе на страницу localhost:8888/blog/тестовый-пост-1/ страница отображается без стилей, но с классами. Подскажите, как я могу, подключить стандартные стили wp или же взять таковые из другой темы, например, 2021/2022, спасибо!

Ниже мой `functions.php`

```
function marathon_assets() {
        wp_enqueue_style('maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/styles/css/index.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper-style', 'https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css');

        wp_register_script('swiper-script', 'https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js', array(), null, 'in_footer');

        wp_enqueue_script('swiper-script');
        wp_enqueue_script('smoothScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/smoothScroll.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('tabs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/tabs.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slider.js', array(), null, 'in_footer');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'marathon_assets');
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/theme/child-theme

Comment: @DarthKYL Спасибо! То есть мне нужно создать на основе стандартной темы дочернюю, в которой уже прописывать весь свой нужный мне функционал, а все стили подтянутся из родительской?

Comment: @DarthKYL к сожалению, все еще выводится главная страница